# Sumif with multiple criteria but avoiding duplicates (and w/wildcards)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, sumifs

I have a dataset where I need to sum up sales values of all the products with three different criteria. The issue is, there are many products where these criteria overlap, but I don't want to double (or triple) count (I'm not using the sumifs formula because that's for when there are multiple criteria that must fit--"AND"--and in this case, I need "OR"). To make matters more complicated, I need to use wildcards because the text I'm searching for is accompanied by other text (luckily my keyword will only appear once per cell). I've created a very basic dataset here to use as an example as I can't upload our sensitive data (forgive my lack of knowledge of cars). Let's say I want to sum the value of all Saabs, white cars, and cars made in the year 2022 (any of those, not all--in other words, OR not AND), but I don't want the value of any of the same cars counted twice.

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

The cell that says "Manufacturer" in the top left is A1. If I use the sumif formula and add together all the Saabs, white cars, and cars made in the year 2022, I will be double-counting car JCT835, VUT613, and OCY365.

The kicker is though that there are some instances where the same exact car (see ID number) appears more than once in the data (see the red highlighted cells for duplicate values), and in those cases, I don't ever want the sales data to be double-counted. In the actual dataset, the ID number will be identical, but the other cells in the same row will not be--they will contain the company name once but with other text, which will be different, which is why I try to use wildcards (the sales data will always be the same number though). What I've done is create a new column that divides the sales total by the number of instances of that item, so the overall total stays the same (column F). Cell F2's formula is: =E2/COUNTIF($D$2:$D$18, D2)

Any help you could provide would be most appreciated!!

I've been thinking about creating another helper column but and then maybe some sumif formula to subtract the duplicates but it's a bit advanced for me. I tried it on an earlier iteration of this example spreadsheet, and it worked fine until, for the sake of experimentation, I added in two more rows (the last two rows in the screenshot and table at the bottom), the first was irrelevant, but the second was a (unique) white 2022 Saab with a value of 9000. While the result then should have been 114,000, the formula returned 96,000. In other words, it wouldn't work for a huge dataset (what I'm dealing with) because of the number of instances where double-and triple-counting would occur, and me not knowing how to sort that out with Sumifs. Here's the formula I used:

=SUMPRODUCT(F2:F18*((A2:A18="Saab")+(B2:B18="White")+(C2:C18=2022)))-(SUMIFS(F2:F18,A2:A18,"Saab",B2:B18,"White")+SUMIFS(F2:F18,B2:B18,"White",C2:C18,2022)+SUMIFS(F2:F18,A2:A18,"Saab",C2:C18,2022)+SUMIFS(F2:F18,A2:A18,"Saab",B2:B18,"White",C2:C18,2022))

Finally, here's the table copied (from Office 365). The first cell ("Manufacturer") is A1. And just so we're all clear, the answer should be: 5500 + 5500 + 12000 + 12000 + 9000 + 9000 (all the Saabs) + 13000 + 10000 (all the white cars that haven't yet been counted) + 13000 + 17000 + 8000 (cars from 2022 that haven't yet been counted) = 114000.

| Manufacturer | Color | Year | ID Number | Value | Value (considering duplicates) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Random text Toyota | Gray Random text | 2020 | ABH749 | 10000 | 10000 |
| Random text Saab | White Random text | 2021 | JCT835 | 11000 | 5500 |
| Renault Random text | Random White text | 2020 | GUK498 | 13000 | 13000 |
| Saab Random text | Random text White | 2021 | JCT835 | 11000 | 5500 |
| Random text Audi | Black Random text | 2020 | IUP140 | 18000 | 18000 |
| Random Saab text | Yellow Random text | 2022 | WTC659 | 12000 | 12000 |
| Toyota Random text | Random text Red | 2023 | PUN261 | 13000 | 13000 |
| Random text Renault | Random Red text | 2022 | UVD976 | 13000 | 13000 |
| Random text Toyota | Blue Random text | 2021 | REW710 | 14000 | 14000 |
| Audi Random text | Green Random text | 2022 | VKB396 | 17000 | 17000 |
| Random text Saab | Random text Blue | 2022 | OCY356 | 12000 | 12000 |
| Saab Random text | Random text White | 2020 | VUT613 | 9000 | 9000 |
| Volkswagen Random text | Random Red text | 2022 | NVB989 | 8000 | 8000 |
| Random text Fiat | Random Gray text | 2021 | GHB932 | 6000 | 6000 |
| Random Renault text | Random White text | 2022 | MDA232 | 10000 | 10000 |
| Random Volkswagen text | Random text Gray | 2021 | GUB838 | 7000 | 7000 |
| Random Saab text | Random text White | 2022 | VUG879 | 9000 | 9000 |

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the destination worksheet (range) with row and column headers this time? Also, sample data copied as text would make things easier.

Comment: Would you provide your sample data in **table markdown format**, it takes time to reproduce it. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) just copy from your excel, then generate the format and copy into your question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLeal, great tip! I've since added this into the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Go with `FILTER()` then `UNIQUE()` and sum those unique values.

```
=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:E6,(A2:A6="Saab")*(B2:B6="White")*(C2:C6=2022))),,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Most of your answers are O365 specific.  I would highly recommend that you start your answers out with a reference to being O365-only.  A surprising percentage of questions here are still from pre-O365 users.

Comment: @MaxR why not address the posters to make sure they include the version of Excel when they post? Much better all round. And as for you saying "most" of Harun’s answers - did you check ALL of them? Or just the ones you have seen recently?

Comment: @MaxR OP should mention correct version of his/her Excel. Once version is not mentioned then we assume OP is using latest version. Also, if answer is not suitable with OP's excel version then just post a comment.

Comment: You've summed the value of cars that are Saabs AND white AND made in the year 2022. I want OR not AND, but then to not count the same rows twice (for example, I don't a white Saab to be counted twice or a white Saab made in 2022 to be counted three times).

Comment: @exc2023 for the OR condition replace Harun24hr's formula in second input argument of `FILTER` the multiplication with `+`

Comment: Ahhhh shoot, just realized there's another problem. The data I'm actually working with has multiple columns of sales totals, one for each financial year. This appears to be summing everything in the array, so it only works for the first financial year (in the next column when trying to sum for the second financial year, the sales totals from both the first and the second financial year get added up, and so on for the years that follow).

I could create a new spreadsheet for every financial year, but is there another solution?

Comment: To make matters worse, I copied and pasted this formula into the actual spreadsheet I'm working on (not the example), and I got a #CALC! error. Here's what it looks like: 

=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:AE75969,(A2:A75969="*Company name*")+(E2:E75969="*Company name*")+(AB2:AB75969="*Company name*"))),,-1))

The company name can appear in any of three different columns (sometimes more than once in the same row). When I click on the error symbol, it says "empty array." And when I click on calculation steps, after "AE75969," (without the quotes), I get: "{0;0;0...})),,-1))" with thousands of 0s.

Comment: In case it helps, the italicization of "Company name" was unintential. I was merely using a partial match " * Company name * " without the spaces around the *. I can't imagine that's the issue though.

Comment: Scratch that, apparently the wildcards are the problem, because when I get rid of the asterisks, I do get a result--it's just not the result I need (because I need partial matches here, the company name appears only once but in a block of text). Any idea how to use this formula with wildcards? (If it helps, in my actual spreadsheet, the ID numbers are the duplicates, while the other cells in that row will be different--this is why I'm using wildcards.) @Harun24hr ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with adding a helper column, which you can fill down with-
assuming col `D` is `ID Number`

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,D1:D$1,0)),E2,0)
```

[image: 1]

This works by

- `MATCH()` if the `ID Number`s in `D` *above* the cell on the same row include the cell on the same row returns relative index or ERROR (didn't MATCH)
- `ISERROR()` returns `True` (found duplicate) or `False` (didn't match)
- `IF()` there was an ERROR, use the same row in `Value`, otherwise `0`

Caveats

- if the `Value` is not the same for two `ID Number` pairs, the first will be used, ignoring later instances
  this can be fixed this by adding *another* column which just appends `ID Number` and `Value` to make a new key `=D2&E2` (though this can be further fooled by very special cases, it doesn't seem likely)
- if another `ID Number` is literally `ID Number`, start at `D3` and skip row 2 (manually filling it across because it can't be a duplicate)

Comment: This is interesting. What are the advantages to using this formula compared to the formula I used in column F (see OP)?

Comment: And how do we get the sum we're looking for (105000--see edited OP).

Comment: perhaps nothing logic-wise (if the results differ, that might be more interesting), but I've generally found extra columns useful to both create an incremental workflow, (each column is a new step, which helps write the workflow) and generally to debug each part of that workflow, and also to help explain what's happening (this can even be in the form of a humble Note) .. however, I would further argue all use of Excel et al. is a bridge to view and explore data before handling it in another more structured program ; with the duplicates set to `0`, `SUM()` should be sufficient!

Comment: re-reading your solution of dividing the values, I would take some caution as to never present data that can taken in part to be True, when really it has been transformed into an untrue state (ie. `5500` is a plausible value, while `0`, `#NA`, `False`, etc. are unlikely to be mistaken in a future analysis)

Comment: Excellent points!

Comment: One advantage though is that in some cases, I might not want the number to be a 0 because that would mean 0 sales, when in reality, there have been sales.

Comment: surely those sales are accounted for in a previous row! however, if entries of `Value` `0` or other generally troublesome data exists in your dataset, consider doing two rounds and first cleaning the data by removing duplicates or other logic from the data (or even better fixing the input data process so they are never created) and putting your new input down into another sheet to save yourself so much trouble

Answer (score 0):

*I am only addressing the first part of your question, not the duplicates part.  You referenced SUMIF() which led me to believe you are not familiar with the built-in SUMIFS() function that provides for multiple criteria.*

There are two approaches to this, and both of these:

- Make no assumption that you have Excel O365
- Do not require helper columns
- Assume you are still handling duplicate IDs in some way

**SUMIFS() Approach**

This is the "easy button".  I do not know your specific columns and ranges, so I will use general terms and you can replace them in your spreadsheet with the specific ranges:

`=SUMIFS( valueRange, colorRange, "White", modelRange, "Saab", yearRange, 2002)`

**SUMPRODUCT() Approach**

I very often rely on the SUMPRODUCT approach instead of the SUMIFS, because I am used to it and it is robust--it allows any combination of AND and OR criteria:

`=SUMPRODUCT( (colorRange="White) * (modelRange="Saab") * (yearRange=2002) * valueRange )`

The SUMPRODUCT() approach takes a little practice to master but it is an extremely valuable advanced Excel skill that is well worth the learning curve if you do this kind of work often.  Once you get used to the SUMPRODUCT approach you'll probably just stop using SUMIFS most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a scripted example (as [hinted at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75424166/sumif-with-multiple-criteria-but-avoiding-duplicates/75424307?noredirect=1#comment133111778_75424307)), tooling like Python + Pandas can trivially do this for you (note duplicate index 3 is dropped, but the original indices ordering is kept)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("data_75424166.txt", sep="\t")  # copied from post
>>> df.drop_duplicates()  # defaults to all rows
   Manufacturer   Color  Year ID Number  Value
0        Toyota    Gray  2020    ABH749  10000
1          Saab   White  2021    JCT835  11000
2       Renault   White  2020    GUK498  13000
4          Audi   Black  2020    IUP140  18000
5          Saab  Yellow  2022    WTC659  12000
6        Toyota     Red  2023    PUN261  13000
7       Renault     Red  2022    UVD976  13000
8        Toyota    Blue  2021    REW710  14000
9          Audi   Green  2022    VKB396  17000
10         Saab    Blue  2022    OCY356  12000
11         Saab   White  2020    VUT613   9000
12   Volkswagen     Red  2022    NVB989   8000
13         Fiat    Gray  2021    GHB932   6000
14      Renault   White  2022    MDA232  10000
```

Example dropping duplicated Manufacturer rows

```py
>>> df.drop_duplicates(["Manufacturer"])
   Manufacturer  Color  Year ID Number  Value
0        Toyota   Gray  2020    ABH749  10000
1          Saab  White  2021    JCT835  11000
2       Renault  White  2020    GUK498  13000
4          Audi  Black  2020    IUP140  18000
12   Volkswagen    Red  2022    NVB989   8000
13         Fiat   Gray  2021    GHB932   6000
```

Total filtering

```py
>>> df.drop_duplicates(["ID Number"]).loc[(df["Manufacturer"] == "Saab") | (df["Color"] == "White") | (df["Year"] == 2022) ]
   Manufacturer   Color  Year ID Number  Value
1          Saab   White  2021    JCT835  11000
2       Renault   White  2020    GUK498  13000
5          Saab  Yellow  2022    WTC659  12000
7       Renault     Red  2022    UVD976  13000
9          Audi   Green  2022    VKB396  17000
10         Saab    Blue  2022    OCY356  12000
11         Saab   White  2020    VUT613   9000
12   Volkswagen     Red  2022    NVB989   8000
14      Renault   White  2022    MDA232  10000
>>> df.drop_duplicates(["ID Number"]).loc[(df["Manufacturer"] == "Saab") | (df["Color"] == "White") | (df["Year"] == 2022) ]["Value"].sum()
105000
```

Related documentation

- [`.drop_duplicates()` behavior](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)
- Directly [reading Excel files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [writing Excel files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: I know a bit of R, but this has to be done entirely in Excel because it is building upon the work of a colleague that was done in Excel.